# In JavaScript is there a way to make the variables global as you can do in python

Tags: javascript

```
//gets the username from the text box
function getUsername() {
let username = document.getElementById("usernameBox").value;
}
//alerts the user there username p.s. the site is still under development.
function sayUsername() {
alert(userename);
}
```

I keep getting the error message that the username variable does not exist, even though it is set in the function above. So my question is, how do I make the username variable set in both functions?

I have tried to put all the code above plus the other code for website in the same function, but that gives me errors. Then I have tried to make the username and password get put into an array but the values change when a different person logs in. So how do I make the variables work in all functions?

Comment: If you don't use a variable declaration like `let` then the variable will be global by default.

Comment: Why don't you use `return` instead of a global variable? That's the best way in most languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let username

function getUsername() {
  username = document.getElementById("usernameBox").value;
}

function sayUsername() {
  alert(userename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it global by declaring it outside the function but global variables give rise to errors, so better will be call the `sayUsername` from `getUsername` function and pass `username` as a paramater to the function

```js
function getUsername() {
  let username = document.getElementById("usernameBox").value;
  sayUsername(username)
}

function sayUsername(userename) {
  alert(userename);
}
```